# Laravel Getting Logged out

Tags: database, laravel, session

I get randomly logged out in laravel. After trying to login again I randomly get the page reloaded or a Token Mismatch (or logged in).

After changing to the Session Database Drive (Problem still persisting) I've noticed that it creates new sessions for every login try. It also creates a session when logging out... But not when moving pages.

I noticed that alot of my session rows contain NULL for the user_id.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: I had this problem a year ago. I had a route which grabbed files (mostly to display images) and sent them to the client, the problem was that this route was inside the web route group and because it was each a new request without an auth header Laravel logged me out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I resolved it (hadnt had a logout since then). I shared a model with all my views in order to show the 3 latest news in my footer. Removed that and it seems to work.